Crash after inserting an image with a controlled React component using Quill.js
I am implementing a React component using the Quill library.
I'm having a problem inserting an image into the text editor. When I select the image, the editor crashes and the whole page freezes. It is only after many seconds that the image is inserted into the editor. However, after that I still can't do anything, the crash persists. I have to refresh the page...
Here is what I currently have:
// EditorField.tsx

[...] // All imports.

const IMAGE_ACCEPT = '.png, .jpeg, .jpg';
const IMAGE_MAX_SIZE = SIZES_BYTES.Mo;

/**
 * EditorField component.
 *
 * @param {EditorFieldProps} props Props
 * @return {JSX.Element}
 */
const EditorField = forwardRef(
  (
    {
      className,
      errorMessage,
      helperText,
      label,
      onChange,
      placeholder,
      readOnly,
      required,
      toolbar = EDITORFIELD_TOOLBAR.DEFAULT,
      value,
      ...attr
    }: EditorFieldProps,
    ref?: ForwardedRef<HTMLDivElement>,
  ) => {
    const containerRef = useForwardedRef<HTMLDivElement>(ref);
    const quillRef = useRef<Quill | null>(null);
    const inputRef = useRef<HTMLInputElement>(null);

    const [editorErrorMessage, setEditorErrorMessage] = useState<string>('');

    const classNames = clsx('OmniEditorField', className);

    /**
     * Function called when the text changes.
     *
     * @return {void}
     */
    const onTextChange = useCallback((): void => {
      const html =
        containerRef.current?.querySelector('.ql-editor')?.innerHTML || '';

      onChange(html === '<p><br></p>' ? '' : html);
    }, [containerRef, onChange]);

    /**
     * Add image in editor.
     *
     * @param {ChangeEvent<HTMLInputElement>} event Event
     * @return {Promise<void>}
     */
    const handleAddImage = async (
      event: ChangeEvent<HTMLInputElement>,
    ): Promise<void> => {
      const file = event.target.files?.[0];
      const currentSelection = quillRef.current?.getSelection();

      if (!file || !quillRef.current || !currentSelection) return;

      // Removes a previous error that may have occurred.
      setEditorErrorMessage('');

      // Check image size.
      if (file.size > IMAGE_MAX_SIZE) {
        setEditorErrorMessage(
          `La taille de l'image ne doit pas dépasser la limite de ${formatBytes(IMAGE_MAX_SIZE)}`,
        );
        return;
      }

      // Check image type.
      if (!checkFileType(file, IMAGE_ACCEPT)) {
        setEditorErrorMessage("Le type de l'image n'est pas autorisé.");
        return;
      }

      // Insert image.
      await convertFileToBase64(file)
        .then((file64) => {
          quillRef.current?.editor.insertEmbed(
            currentSelection.index,
            'image',
            file64,
          );
          quillRef.current?.insertText(currentSelection.index + 1, '\n');
          quillRef.current?.setSelection(currentSelection.index + 2);
        })
        .catch(() => {
          setEditorErrorMessage(
            "Une erreur s'est produite lors de l'insertion de l'image.",
          );
        });
    };

    useEffect(() => {
      const container = containerRef.current;
      if (!container) return;

      // Init quill.
      const quill = new Quill(
        container.appendChild(container.ownerDocument.createElement('div')),
        {
          modules: {
            toolbar: {
              container: toolbar,
              handlers: {
                image: (imageValue: boolean) => {
                  if (imageValue) {
                    inputRef.current?.click();
                  }
                },
              },
            },
          },
          placeholder,
          theme: 'snow',
        },
      );
      quillRef.current = quill;

      // eslint-disable-next-line consistent-return
      return () => {
        container.innerHTML = '';
      };

      // eslint-disable-next-line react-hooks/exhaustive-deps
    }, []);

    // Set events.
    useEffect(() => {
      quillRef.current?.on(Quill.events.TEXT_CHANGE, onTextChange);

      return () => {
        quillRef.current?.off(Quill.events.TEXT_CHANGE, onTextChange);
      };
    }, [onTextChange]);

    // Set read only.
    useEffect(() => {
      quillRef.current?.enable(!readOnly);
    }, [quillRef, readOnly]);

    // Set value.
    useEffect(() => {
      if (!quillRef.current || quillRef.current.hasFocus()) return;

      const currentSelection = quillRef.current.getSelection();

      quillRef.current.setContents(
        quillRef.current.clipboard.convert({ html: value }),
      );
      quillRef.current.setSelection(currentSelection);
    }, [value]);

    return (
      <div className={classNames} data-testid="OmniEditorField">
        <FormLabel as="span" required={required}>
          {label}
        </FormLabel>

        <FormHelperText>{helperText}</FormHelperText>

        <input
          accept={IMAGE_ACCEPT}
          className="OmniEditorField__file"
          hidden
          onChange={handleAddImage}
          ref={inputRef}
          type="file"
        />

        <div className="OmniEditorField__field" ref={containerRef} {...attr} />

        <FormErrorMessage>
          {editorErrorMessage || errorMessage}
        </FormErrorMessage>
      </div>
    );
  },
);

export { EditorField };

// EditorField.stories.tsx

[...] // All imports.

// Types.
type Meta = MetaStorybook<EditorFieldProps>;
type Story = StoryObj<EditorFieldProps>;

// Metadata.
const meta: Meta = {
  component: EditorField,
  tags: ['autodocs'],
  title: 'Composants/Formulaire/EditorField',
};

export default meta;

// Stories.
export const EditorFieldStory: Story = {
  name: 'Champ de base',
  args: {
    helperText: 'Parlez nous un peu de vous !',
    label: 'Biographie',
    placeholder: 'Saisissez votre biographie...',
    required: true,
    value: "Je m'appelle John Doe...",
  },
  render: ({ value: defaultValue, ...args }) => {
    const [value, setValue] = useState<string>(defaultValue);

    return <EditorField {...args} value={value} onChange={setValue} />;
  },
};

// helpers.ts

[...] // All imports.

/**
 * Convert a file to base64.
 *
 * @example
 * const file64 = await convertFileToBase64(file);
 * @param {File} file File to convert
 * @return {Promise<string>}
 */
export function convertFileToBase64(file: File): Promise<string> {
  return new Promise((resolve, reject) => {
    const reader = new FileReader();

    reader.readAsDataURL(file);
    reader.onload = () => resolve(reader.result?.toString() || '');
    reader.onerror = reject;
  });
}

Some project package versions:
"quill": "2.0.2",
"react": "18.3.1",
"react-dom": "18.3.1",
"vite": "5.2.12",
"typescript": "5.2.2",
"storybook": "8.1.5",

If the field is not controlled, everything works without problems but as I want to make a custom controlled component with the value and onChange properties, I have problems.
I tried, as in the quill example, to use only "ref" but without success.
I tried to understand the problem, the editor does not crash if I replace the value like this :
/**
 * Add image in editor.
 *
 * @param {ChangeEvent<HTMLInputElement>} event Event
 * @return {Promise<void>}
 */
const handleAddImage = async (
  event: ChangeEvent<HTMLInputElement>,
): Promise<void> => {

[...]

// Insert image.
await convertFileToBase64(file)
  .then((file64) => {
    quillRef.current?.editor.insertEmbed(
      currentSelection.index,
      'image',
      '', // Replace file64 into empty string.
    );
    quillRef.current?.insertText(currentSelection.index + 1, '\n');
    quillRef.current?.setSelection(currentSelection.index + 2);
  })
  .catch(() => {
    setEditorErrorMessage(
      "Une erreur s'est produite lors de l'insertion de l'image.",
    );
  });

If I hide the onChange function, again the editor does not crash:
 /**
 * Function called when the text changes.
 *
 * @return {void}
 */
const onTextChange = useCallback((): void => {
  const html =
    containerRef.current?.querySelector('.ql-editor')?.innerHTML || '';

  // onChange(html === '<p><br></p>' ? '' : html);
}, [containerRef, onChange]);

